# Design a full subtractor using 4 to 1 MUX and an inverter

Tags: multiplexer

I can't wrap my head around it. Any tips?

I need to draw a circuit diagram of a Full Subtractor using 4-to-1 Multiplexers and an Inverter.

FS diagram:

[image: subtractor]
<sub>(source: [ustudy.in](http://ustudy.in/sites/default/files/fullsub.gif))</sub>

MUX diagram:

[image: multiplexer]
<sub>(source: [surrey.ac.uk](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/multiplexer/graphics/multiplexer.gif))</sub>

Do I need to combine them somehow?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suspect this is homework, is this the entire question?

Comment: It is homework. I don't even know where to start. I edited my question with diagrams of a FS and 4-1 MUX.

Comment: Also asked at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/18636/16322

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework without any demonstrated effort and also unclear now the first image link is dead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

since there are two outputs(sub and borrow) we have to select 2 multiplexers. Start with the truth table of full subtractor. Use karnaugh maps(it will make your life simpler). Select 2 variables as your select line. For example B and C in my case. The truth table is as follows
[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8dMmC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpQ03l.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I got it, will study it more when I get home.

Comment: What about the 'inverter' part of the question though? Also, don't I need to connect the 2 diagrams?

Comment: The NOT gate that I have used is the INVERTER. They are 2 different outputs. They can be given to 2 LED for indication

Comment: There's a reason we don't provide direct answers to homework questions. You know, *"Give a man a fish, he eats for a day. Teach a man to fish, he eats for a lifetime."* In this case, we want to teach the OP how to solve this class of problem, not hand him a solution for this specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly a homework question, and I'm not doing your homework for you (the world doesn't need any more engineers that shouldn't have survived uni).  However, I will give you a hint: you can implement truth tables with a multiplexer.

Comment: Thanks. So I could implement the full subtractor's truth table using a multiplexer?

Comment: You can implement *any* purely combinational truth table of the appropriate size with a multiplexer.

Answer (score 0):

Let it be generalized for any system we need to implement using a multiplexer.

1. **step 1:** Take the inputs of the circuit to implement as the select lines for the multiplexer. That is for your convenience just write the select line variables above the input variables.
2. **step 2:** Have a look at the output sop for the given circuit. Mux only has one output so you will be asked to implement only one output from one mux. From the sop mark the terms with 1 and provide them a high input. That is basically marking the min terms.
3. **step 3** Mark the terms with zero in the output and provide the corresponding inputs zero. That is by marking the max terms